# CS1022 but there are no missing brackets

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Visual Studio has been very annoying and is not recognizing matching parentheses for some reason. The problem only appears after typing 2 lines into the brackets, when they are empty everything is fine. I have the latest update and have checked to make sure I don't have any weird indentation settings. Code is below:

```
public class Control : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        public static int gamesPlayed = 0;
        public static int weeks = 0;
        public static int difficulty = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot declare fields *inside* of a method, which is what you've done with `gamesPlayed` etc inside of `Start`. You need to move these out so they are at class level:

```
public static int gamesPlayed = 0;
public static int weeks = 0;
public static int difficulty = 0; 
void Start() { 

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can’t declare public or static variables in a method. That’s why it thinks there’s missing brackets. Anything declared in a method is only for the method

Move them out of start